# Filtering Data In Excel Using VB

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to filter data in Visual basic by filtering out any values that read "#N/A" and I would like to keep the rest, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the [ISNA function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isna.php).

Perhaps something like this:

```
Sheets(1).Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=<>Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Range("A1").Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an IF INSTR statement.  You can find the syntax here.  http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php